# Why is apple vim compiled WITHOUT conceal feature?

Tags: macos, vim, cross-compiling, vim-plugin

I noticed this fact trying to use [Yggdroot/indentLine plugin](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine), which requires conceal feature.

```
$ /usr/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
...
```

Vim > 7.3 usually supports +conceal feature.

Does anybody know why apple explicitly excluded conceal feature when compile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not the only thing Apple's Vim is missing. Do yourself a favour and brew install macvim or nvim, both are head and shoulders above the default vim.

Comment: Why would they include it?

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to tell why exactly that's the choice they took. Only an Apple
employee would be  able to help us in explaining  this. However, I don't
think it's an explicit exclusion of `conceal` by itself.

When  you compile  Vim, the  configure script  accepts an  option called
`--with-features`  which controls  a set  of features  to be  enabled or
disabled.

```
--with-features=TYPE.  tiny, small, normal, big or huge (default: huge)
```

<sup>*from [src/auto/configure L1532](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/9cea87c5775948a35098f3602746c20ecf95dbcd/src/auto/configure#L1532)*</sup>

The  `conceal`  feature  is  only  enabled with  *big*  or  *huge*,  and
dependent on `+syntax`:

```
/*
 * +conceal     'conceal' option.  Needs syntax highlighting
 *          as this is how the concealed text is defined.
 */
#if defined(FEAT_BIG) && defined(FEAT_SYN_HL)
# define FEAT_CONCEAL
#endif
```

<sup>*from [src/feature.h L496-502](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/effed9315c6c5a35fc2824b90da4af753c7a02dc/src/feature.h#L496-L502)*</sup>

You can  see a handy  list of  what is included  in each feature  set by
checking `:h  +feature-list`. Thus, judging  by the other  features, I'd
say  `conceal` is  disabled just  because  they are  compiling with  the
feature set option `--with-features=normal`.

It's  highly recommended  to  install  a newer  and  more complete  Vim.
Replacing the  system program might  not be optimal, but  that's exactly
why there are  plenty of alternatives which take care  of doing it right
and  keeping  Vim  updated  and  complete.  If  you  have  [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)
installed, a simple command will do:

```
$ brew install vim
```

Alternatively,  if  you  have  MacVim  you can  also  use  its  internal
executable by making an alias on your shell or something similar.

Comment: hmm, i might have been unfair to point out 'conceal' among other missing features. the feature is often super convenient for japanese users (and others in non-alphabetish culture maybe) and i couldn't think of any reason not to include it so was unconsciously supposing all vim > 7.3 would have it. i was expecting an answer like "it collides with foo bar apple provides" or one like why apple ships bash version 3, but it may be only a coincident or only apple employees know... of course i've already brew-installed vim and enjoying the plugin. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I suppose the question then becomes why `conceal` is considered a "big" feature and not a "normal" one...